# Trying to create an array of objects but it keeps using index 0 to store all of my objects

Tags: java, arrays, object, processing

I am trying to create an array of objects, more specifically buttons or "rectangles", but when I initialize the elements using a for loop it appears that when I assign the object to an index it they are all stored in index 0 of the array.

This is the class that I am working in:

[image: http://gyazo.com/f012368671d23fc02bca250c3948775b]

and this is the class I am trying to create an object of:

[image: http://gyazo.com/c91cb0dac82b3c8ca9e0b3a8ab473b8a]

[image: Program when it runs]

![image: Image of the class I am working from]

```
import  java.util.Arrays;
class ButtonPanel {

  Internet i;
  Button b;
  Button[] buttons;

  ButtonPanel() {
    i = new Internet();
    stroke(28, 215, 234);
    noFill();
    rect(width, 0, -i.getX(), height);
    buttons = new Button[3];
  } 

  void drawButtons() {
    rectMode(CORNER);
    fill(255);
    translate(1040, -105);
   for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) { 
     buttons[i]= new Button(0, i*90, -width/2, 90);
      // work out proper calculations 
      // work out how to manipulate individual indexes
     buttons[0].addColor(color(0));
    }

    //for (int j = 0; j < switches.length; j++) {
    //switches[0] = new Button(j*-width/6, -90, -width/6, 90);
    //}
    }
  void addPanel() {
    drawButtons();
  }
}
```

Comment: You can use an external link for illustrative purposes, but the code still needs to be here, in your question, directly.

Comment: What language is it ?

Comment: Java, I am using Processing. I have updated my post accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

What makes you suspect everything is stored on index 0?

This loop should work, since `i` is starting at 0 and increases until it reaches `buttons.length` (which should be 2), and you're assigning the new Buttons to `buttons[i]`. Concluding from this, your loop should run twice, assigning unique `Button` objects to `buttons[0]` and `buttons[1]`.

Comment: Sorry I am new to this website, I edited my post to show you the outcome of the program.

Comment: Why are you using `buttons[0].addColor(color(0));`? If you only want to edit the first one, you should move that statement outside your loop. Otherwise, you should replace the [0] with [i] (as it used to be...).

Further more, I still don't get why you think all Buttons are assigned to index 0.

Comment: I was playing around with that statement to try and manipulate the array hehe, outside of the for loop it appears to do nothing- all I really want to do is to be able to manipulate each button individually but have it created in a for loop...

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not create the buttons in draw method, do so in the constructor. Each thing should do only one thing :)

Same thing in Buttons, don't draw in the constructor, make a display() method. If you call `addColor()` it won't work cause the rects are already drew.

the structure might look some thing like this:

```
ButtonPanel bp =new ButtonPanel();

void setup() {
  size(300, 200);
  bp.drawButtons();
}
class ButtonPanel {

  Button[] buttons;

  ButtonPanel() {

    buttons = new Button[3];
    for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) { 
      buttons[i]= new Button(100+i*35, 100, 30, 30);
    }
  } 

  void drawButtons() {
    stroke(28, 215, 234);
    noFill();
    rect(90, 90, 120, 50);
    for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
      buttons[i].addColor(color(random(255), random(255), random(100)));
      buttons[i].display();
    }
  }
}

class Button {
  int x, y, w, h;
  color c;
  Button(int _x, int _y, int _w, int _h) {
    x = _x;
    y = _y;
    w = _w;
    h = _h;
    c = color(100, 100, 100);
  }

  void display() {
    fill(c);
    stroke(255);
    rect(x, y, w, h);
  }
  void addColor(color newC) {
    c = newC;
  }
}
```